# Folder with a million files - how to use Powershell to limit the returned file list to a maximum number of files and avoid the hours-long wait?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have a directory that inadvertently had about 1.4 million files generated into it. I want to list just the first, say, 100 items, but without the underlying process trying to read the entire directory contents internally, which causes a very long wait which, at this stage, has been processing for nearly an hour.

How do I do this with Powershell?

Comment: this question seems to belong to stackoverflow.Maybe last post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078920/equivalent-of-more-command-in-powershell would be helpful ?

Comment: Is powershell operation not a system administration issue?

Comment: It is  used by system administrators, however your question sounds like a coding task.Nothing wrong to have it here, but I think you are more likely to have question answered among coders.

Comment: Fair enough. It's not a coding task, I just want to delete files. I'm using FastCopy now, which seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: @Sergei : The last post in that stackoverflow thread implies that you take ALL the content and pipe it through a selection filter. That way, Nathan would have to wait for the 1.4 million file handles to get loaded into memory, just to discard 1.3999 million of them :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Want the first hundred items in a directory?

```
@(dir)[1..100]
```

Only want files?

```
@(dir -File)[1..100]
```

Want to skip the first `40` directories and get the next 200?

```
@(dir -Directory)[41..240]
```

Comment: This will still read through all files and then return a list of the preferred length.

Comment: It most certainly will, it just won't print them all to the screen